# How do I add an element to an array using Redux Thunk?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm creating an app that should allow instructors to add courses to their dashboard only the course name is not being saved to the store.

```js
export const addCourse = (name, instructor) => {
  return function(dispatch) {
    axios.post(`http://localhost:3001/api/courses`, {
      name: name,
      _creator: instructor
    })
    .then(response => {
      cookies.get('instructor', response.data.instructor)
      dispatch({
      type: ADD_COURSE,
      coursename: name,
      _creator: cookies.get('instructor')
      })
      console.log(response.data)
    })
  }
}
```

and the reducer is below

```js
const INITIAL_STATE = {
 coursename: [''],
 _creator: [{}]
}

export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {

  switch(action.type) {
    case ADD_COURSE:
      return {...state,
        coursename: [...state.coursename, action.coursename],
        _creator: action._creator
      }
  }
  return state;
}
```

What am I missing that the user's input will not save to the store arra?y

Comment: Have you checked to see if the `ADD_COURSE` case is being reached?

Comment: Also, it looks like you are using `cookie.get` (the first one) when you probably meant to use `cookie.set`. Why not use `response.data.instructor` directly?

Comment: Actually, it was working as intended, my bad. When I did a console.log(this.props.coursename) it was returning blank on submit but after I added in the code to make this.props.coursename visible on the component it was showing up. Yes, that was a mistake. Thanks for catching that, I'm still a beginner to programming

Comment: Ah okay. You're doing pretty well for a beginner. :) Keep up the good work!